# What derogatory terms are there for Chinese people?

Tags: mandarin, word-requests

What derogatory terms are there for Chinese people in Mandarin?

In particular, I am looking for derogatory terms that apply to any person of Chinese ancestry regardless of birthplace, nationality, culture, political affiliation or Chinese language ability. (Examples in English would be "chinaman", "chinky", and "ching chong").

Comment: Since Mandarin is mainly used by Chinese people, so I don't think such a word exist.

Answer (score 1):

**支那**

[bkrs](https://bkrs.info/slovo.php?ch=%E6%94%AF%E9%82%A3):

> phonetic transcription of China (Japanese: Shina), colonial term, generally considered discriminatory
>
> trad./Budd. China (now derogatory)

It is used for example by Japanese occupiers in《劫中劫》:

> 支那人 derog. Chinese

Comment: I tried formatting your answer a bit, but I couldn't find where the last part that I left unquoted came from.

Comment: user composed based on viewing 2015谍战剧《劫中劫》http://tangrentv.com/thread-444.htm

Comment: Are my edits okay?

Comment: maybe derog. should come after "Chinese", in parentheses (user's fault left uncorrected))

Comment: You can edit it up top. I was just trying to make it more readable.

Comment: Is 支那人 still used colloquially?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to avoid using this, for obvious reasons, but you can consider:

**东亚病夫**

*KEY*:

> 1 sick man of Asia, sick man of East Asia (metaphor used by some Western writers in the late 19th and early 20th centuries in reference to the critical condition of China's economy and government, or the poor health of its people
>
> 2 later also variously applied to Japan, the Philippines, and other Asian countries)